# How can I change the first two characters of a string to "01" with C#?

Tags: c#

I have strings like this:

```
var abc = "00345667";
var def = "002776766";
```

The first two characters are always "`00`".  How can I change these to "`01`" ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [Substring(](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)).

```
var res = "01" + abc.Substring(2);
```

**Edit** Some performance consideration when more replacements to be done.

You can use StringBuilder if you have more sub strings to replace, read this article [How to improve string concatenation performance in Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306822/how-to-improve-string-concatenation-performance-in-visual-c)

**String Concatenation VS String Builder**

One technique to improve string concatenation over strcat() in Visual C/C++ is to allocate a large character array as a buffer and copy string data into the buffer. In the .NET Framework, a string is immutable; it cannot be modified in place. The C# + concatenation operator builds a new string and causes reduced performance when it concatenates large amounts of text.

However, the .NET Framework includes a StringBuilder class that is optimized for string concatenation. It provides the same benefits as using a character array in C/C++, as well as automatically growing the buffer size (if needed) and tracking the length for you. The sample application in this article demonstrates the use of the StringBuilder class and compares the performance to concatenation. [Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306822/how-to-improve-string-concatenation-performance-in-visual-c)

Changing "002776766" with "012776766" using StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(def);
sb[1] = '1';    
def = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: @ DotNET Ninja, StringBuilder could be used but when we have many string concatenations, here we have single concatenation.

Comment: @Adil, what about `string.Format` ?

Comment: `var res=String.Format("01{0}",abc.SubString(2));` k @DotNETNinja.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) and [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).

```
string result = string.Format("01{0}", abc.Substring(2));
```

or [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx)

```
string result = Regex.Replace(abc, "^00", "01");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with `Regex.Replace()` which can be found in the namespace `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.

```
abc = Regex.Replace(abc ,"^00","01");
                        |      
                        |
                        |->^ depicts that start of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var abc = "00345667";
var def = "002776766";
string str= string.Format("01{0}", abc.TrimStart('00'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# 8 or above, you can also do it with a [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) operator. It's very readable

```
var res = "01" + abc[2..];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"00".Concat(abc.Substring(2));
"00".Concat(def.Substring(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function Replace in Regex.

```
like   var abc = "00345667";

       var newvar =Regex.Replace(abc, "^00", "01");
```

Comment: and now your solution is similar to mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

```
var abc = "00345667";
var abc = $"01{abc.Substring(2)}";
```